# grep from file that contains multiple columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file called someNumbers.txt with numbers separated by tabs, like:

```
1   1
2   1
5   1
7   1
10  1
```

I would like to search the numbers in the first column of someNumbers.txt in the first column of another file containing numbers, such as evenNumbers.txt:

```
2   1
4   1
6   1
8   1
10  1
```

My desired output is:

```
2   1
10  1
```

In the simpler scenario where someNumbers.txt is:

```
1
2
5
7
10
```

and evenNumbers.txt is:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

I can simply do

`grep -f someNumbers.txt evenNnumbers.txt`

and get the output:

```
2
10
```

What do I do in the case of the tab separated files?
Thank you

Comment: Your `grep` seems to be backwards, searching `evenNumbers.txt` for the lines that matches the patterns in `someNumbers.txt`.  Is that on purpose? Also, that would not work in the single column case if a pattern matches a substring in the text, such as the pattern `2` matching the `2` in the text `20`.

Comment: I want to search for numbers from someNumbers.txt that appear in evenNumbers.txt.

Comment: Tried ```grep -f <(awk 'print "^" $1 "\t"' evenNumbers.txt) someNumbers.txt``` but I get ```awk: cmd. line:1: print "^" $1 "\t"
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error```

Comment: I'd suggest `awk 'NR==FNR{numbers[$1]; next} $1 in numbers' evenNumbers.txt someNumbers.txt` (sure it's a duplicate though)

Comment: steeldriver's `awk`-only solution is better, but to fix the missing braces in my earlier comment:  `grep -f <(awk '{print "^" $1 "\t"}' evenNumbers.txt) someNumbers.txt`.

Comment: Thank you steeldriver and DopeGhoti, both solutions work.

Comment: @steeldriver Duplicate? It's practically a meme!

Comment: I added an answer as "community", as this is certainly a duplicate (or meme!), to show the advantage of using the awk splitting to fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases where your logic is defined by columns, sometimes it is simpler to use `awk` which by default parses the lines and splits to fields. So you don't need to match the beginning of the line or care about white spaces. This example:

```
grep -Ff file2 file1
```

can be written like:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{map[$0]; next} $0 in map' file2 file1
```

For the case you have two columns per file and you want to modify the above, to consider only the first column from each file, it is very simple, instead of the whole line (`$0`) you look for the first field (`$1`):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]; next} $1 in map' file2 file1
```

while with grep you have, to keep only the first column of first file, to match the bountaries of this field, probably like this:

```
grep -f <(awk '{print "^" $1 "[[:space:]]"}' file2) file1
```

where we match the beginning of the line and white space after, or you may want to match end of lines too. Also you don't look for fixed patterns anymore. You need more work in case you modify the fields (e.g. match the second field) or the field separators. When you take adnantage of the `awk` splitting, you don't think about these issues.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and clear answer. My actual file1 and file2 are much bigger and both are sorted in increasing order. I noticed that when I perform the grep -f search as follows ```grep -f file2 file1``` after generating a version of file2 that only has one column I get a much bigger file (that also takes a much longer time to calculate) than I get when I'm running the ```awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]; next} $1 in map' file2 file1``` command. I wonder how to perform the search more efficiently. But maybe that's a separate post already?

Comment: You could look into `join` command also, but I suspect your files are sorted `-n`, not alphabetically. The `awk` solution for this is very efficient, it just reads once all lines of two files, the hash look-up is fast to find matches is fast, and memory usage and time mostly depend on the size of the patterns file. Also it preserves file2 order, if that matters. You may try this: `join file1 <( awk '{print $1}' file2)` or if not sorted this: `join <(sort file1) <( awk '{print $1}' file2 | sort)`. I guess without sorting it is faster.

Comment: Or maybe withourt sorting `join --nocheck-order file1 <( awk '{print $1}' file2)`.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0}' someNumbers.txt evenNumbers.txt
```

output

```
2   1
10  1
```